# Why doesn't String.split(":") work correctly?

Tags: java, string

I have a problem with the `split()` method. I am parsing a response from an API and splitting a time to hours and minutes. I've found out that `split()` gives me the wrong values. I've made a screenshot of my code while debugging to show you:

[image]

As you can see the `time` value is "08:15" but `tTime[0]` is "".

The weird thing is while parsing I am getting the `time` inside the `for` loop and I get "08:15" when I'm reading 10th item; all from 0 to 8 are fine. Is it a problem with my code or the `split()` method itself?

```
@NonNull
    public static String increaseTimeString(String time, int valHours, int valMinutes, boolean saveToDB, String ID, Context context, TimeSavingColumn column){   // time (hh:mm) // czas pojawienia się zadania + czas na akceptację
        String[] tTime = time.split(":");
        String hour = tTime[0];
        String minute = tTime[1];
        tTime = null;
        if(hour.startsWith("0")) {
            tTime = hour.split("0");
            if(tTime.length > 0)  hour = tTime[0];
            else hour = "0";
        }
        tTime = null;
        if(minute.startsWith("0")) {
            tTime = minute.split("0");
            if (tTime.length > 0) minute = tTime[0];
            else minute = "0";
        }

        int iHour = Integer.parseInt(hour);
        int iMinute = Integer.parseInt(minute);

        if(valMinutes != -1){
            iMinute = iMinute + valMinutes;
            while (iMinute >= 60){
                iMinute = iMinute - 60;
                iHour++;
            }
        }

        int days = 0;

        iHour = iHour + valHours;

        String day = String.valueOf(days);

        if (iHour < 10 && iHour > 0) {
            hour = "0" + String.valueOf(iHour);
        } else {
            hour = String.valueOf(iHour);
        }
        if (iMinute < 10) {
            minute = "0" + String.valueOf(iMinute);
        } else {
            minute = String.valueOf(iMinute);
        }

        if(saveToDB){
            DBAcceptedTasks database = new DBAcceptedTasks(context);
            database.open();
            String actualTime = hour + ":" + minute;
            if (column == TimeSavingColumn.START)database.updateTask(ID, null, null, null, null, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, actualTime, null, null);
            if (column == TimeSavingColumn.END)database.updateTask(ID, null, null, null, null, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, null, actualTime, null);
            if (column == TimeSavingColumn.END)database.updateTask(ID, null, null, null, null, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, null, null, actualTime);
        }

        return hour + ":" + minute;
    }
```

Comment: please post code not image. Besides, colors are really not well chosen to highlight values...

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to show values from debugger, Edit.

Comment: "Is it problem with code or `split()` method itself?" Ask yourself what's more likely: is it a problem with code you wrote 5 minutes ago, or with code actively maintained by thousands of people originally written over 20 years ago? :)

Comment: copy-pasting your code into a web-based ide, the code is working, are you sure the string is correct?

Comment: I wrote it 2 or 3 months ago and everything worked fine till now.

Comment: can you mention response? where you are getting time

Comment: if hour/minute starts with "0" why don't you just skip it `hour.substring(1)`? no reason to split - and you could use `LocalTime` to parse and format your time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in this part:

```java
    if(hour.startsWith("0")) {
      tTime = hour.split("0");
      if(tTime.length > 0)  hour = tTime[0];
      else hour = "0";
    }
```

So if your input is "08:15", hour value is "08". Now when you split it using delimiter "0", you get an array `{ "", "8" }`. So, now tTime[0] is "".

Use instead:

```java
    if(hour.startsWith("0")) {
      hour = hour.substring(1);
    }
```

PS: There would be no problem in case the hour doesn't start with a "0".

Comment: it isn't even reaching that point, I get "" inside hour at the start of method as you can see

Comment: can you share the stacktrace, because when I run this code with "08:15" as input, I get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` in line `int iHour = Integer.parseInt(hour);`

Comment: I'm getting same error, it's because `hour == ""`, because of `tTime[0] == ""`

Comment: So your problem is the part I've described above

Comment: Works now. Turns out my interpretation of debugger output was wrong. Thank's a lot mate

Comment: `hour = hour.substring(1);` No, you don't need to do this. You should just totally remove that block. `Integer.parseInt` absolutely does not mind leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the code, try this

```
if(hour.startsWith("0")) {
        tTime = hour.split("0");
        if(tTime.length > 0)  hour = tTime[1];//index should be 1
        else hour = "0";
    }
    tTime = null;
    if(minute.startsWith("0")) {
        tTime = minute.split("0");
        if (tTime.length > 0) minute = tTime[1];//index should be 1
        else minute = "0";
    }
```

Or the best way to handle this is to convert the hour and minutes to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The `split` method works fine, but then you have a block of code starting with `if (hour.startsWith("0"))` which mangles the numbers.

`Integer.parseInt` does not mind numbers which have leading zeros. It will not explode, treat them as octal, or otherwise grumble, so you don't need to do anything special if `hour.startsWith("0")`.

Also, manipulating time is a lot easier as a flat int count of minutes, not separate hours and minutes. Convert that single int back to hours and minutes and days or whatever only for formatting and display:

```
public static String increaseTimeString(
        String time, int minutesToAdd,
        boolean saveToDB, String ID, Context context, TimeSavingColumn column) {
    String[] parts = time.split(":");
    int minutes = (Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * 60) + Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) + minutesToAdd;
    time = String.format("%02d:%02d", (minutes / 60) % 24, minutes % 60);

    if (saveToDB) {
        DBAcceptedTasks database = new DBAcceptedTasks(context);
        database.open();
        database.updateTask(ID, null, null, null, null,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
            column == TimeSavingColumn.START ? time : null,
            column == TimeSavingColumn.END ? time : null,
            column == TimeSavingColumn.END ? time : null);
    }

    return time;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right I have no idea why I made this that way. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

In you code, after the line, `tTime = hour.split("0");`

State of array tTime is `[, 8]`

Hence after `hour = tTime[0]`, hour is the 0th index of array tTime which is  "".